# securly delete already trashed files on OSX

Tags: macos, data-recovery

I have files that I accidentally deleted using the "empty trash" feature. I intended to use the "secure empty" feature that overwrites the data. This because  the Mac is getting its hd swapped (faulty part), but I do not know what they do with the hard drive so for piece of mind I would like to wipe it.

Is there a method or some software that can securely delete already trashed items? I know on PC you can use Recuva but they do not have an OSX version yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the awnser out myself online.. using disk utility you can go to erase > free space > and then select a over write strength (up to 7 times)